# Automatically copy a cell value from one document or sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, transfer

With Google Sheets how do I automatically import a cell value from one file to another?

Or can it only be done between sheets within the same file?

Answer (score 0):

If you search for `reference another spreadsheet in google` in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=reference%20another%20spreadsheet%20in%20google) and click on the second search result you get [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

It explains there that you can import a range of values from another spreadsheet with IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string).
Where spreadsheet_key is the url or the id of the other spreadsheet and range_string is the range e.g. Sheet1!A1:B2.